# MySQL GROUP BY Multiple Columns Exclusive

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some problems with the following MySQL situation.

I have the following table structure:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
| id |  author |    recipient    |        type      |                   data               |     date   |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
|  2 |    1    |        0        | added_item       | { "item_id": "18" }                  | 1352982623 |
| 11 |    1    |        7        | started_follow   |                                      | 1353030567 |
|  9 |    1    |        0        | added_collection | { "collection_id": "18" }            | 1352994561 |
| 12 |    7    |        1        | started_follow   |                                      | 1353030952 |
|  8 |    1    |        1        | started_follow   |                                      | 1352987839 |
| 14 |    1    |        0        | added_collection | { "collection_id": "19" }            | 1353056624 |
| 15 |    7    |        0        | added_collection | { "collection_id": "20" }            | 1353056731 |
| 16 |    1    |        7        | started_follow   |                                      | 1353057009 |
| 17 |    7    |        0        | added_item       | { "item_id": "21" }                  | 1353057054 |
| 24 |    2    |        0        | added_image      | { "image_id": "3", "item_id": "23" } | 1353419642 |
| 23 |    2    |        0        | added_item       | { "item_id": "23" }                  | 1353419159 |
| 22 |    2    |        0        | added_collection | { "collection_id": "22" }            | 1353419146 |
| 25 |    2    |        0        | added_image      | { "image_id": "4", "item_id": "23" } | 1353419644 |
| 26 |    2    |        0        | added_image      | { "image_id": "5", "item_id": "23" } | 1353419646 |
| 27 |    2    |        0        | added_collection | { "collection_id": "23" }            | 1353419953 |
| 28 |    2    |        0        | added_item       | { "item_id": "24" }                  | 1353419961 |
| 29 |    2    |        0        | added_image      | { "image_id": "6", "item_id": "24" } | 1353419982 |
| 30 |    2    |        0        | added_item       | { "item_id": "25" }                  | 1353420424 |
| 31 |    2    |        0        | added_image      | { "image_id": "7", "item_id": "25" } | 1353420435 |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

What I would like to do is group all stories within a number of seconds, where the `author` and `type` fields are the same.

Here's the query I'm using at the moment, but this does not return all instances of the stories, only the first time each `type` occurs per `users`:

```
SELECT  `activity`.`id` AS  `id` 
FROM  `activity` 
INNER JOIN  `user_privacy` ON  `user_privacy`.`user_id` =  `activity`.`author` 
WHERE (
`activity`.`author` =2
OR  `activity`.`recipient` =2
)
AND  `user_privacy`.`include_stream` =1
GROUP BY ROUND( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE ) /300 ) ,  `type` 
ORDER BY  `activity`.`date` DESC 
LIMIT 300
```

I have set up an SQLFiddle demo here > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b5f4/1.

Given the data outlined above, and the query used, I would like to return the following `id`s:

- 22
- 23
- 24
- 27
- 28
- 29
- 30
- 31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps did you mistook UNIX_TIMESTAMP and FROM_UNIXTIME. Just repalce it and your desired result set is there.  [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b5f4/39)